# How to round the corners of all views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I can use `.cornerRadius` to round the corners of specific views. How would I apply this to be general across all views? For example, I want every `Button` or `TextEditor` view in my app to have a corner radius set by default.

Comment: It isn't possible and just FYI `cornerRadius` seems to be a lot more expensive than using `RoundedRectangle` if you apply it everywhere your app will see a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [View styles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view-styles). For example.

```
struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .cornerRadius(3)
    }
}
```

or

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .cornerRadius(3)
    }
}
```

Then you can implement it like

```
TextField("", text: $textEntered)
   .frame(width: 200)
   .textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())
```

Comment: why do all this rigmarole when you can just use `.cornerRadius(3)` instead of `.textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine imagine if you have 2 or more buttons in a single view, you could have styles and you can have many modifiers inside it which is I’m sure the person asking this won’t only be using cornerRadius.

Comment: yes, fair enough, however, the question seems to ask for `cornerRadius` only and 
for a general way to apply to all Views. Of course, as you have it, you can apply the style with more than just the 
`cornerRadius` modifier.